# Spring set a property using a runtime object?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, instantiation

I have a hard time figuring out how to set a property with the help of spring annotations.

I have an abstract base class.

```
abstract class AbstractTest{
 private static Session session;

 @BeforeClass
 public static void initApplication() throws Exception {
  session = new Session();
  ...
 }

 public Session getSession(){
```

I have an test class extending my AbstractTest.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class RealTest extends AbstractTest{

 @Autowired
 Service service;
```

I have a service that needs to make use of the session object and I want it to be "autoset" to the session object.

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

// @AutoSomething how to make this work?
private Session session;
```

The spring file that is automatically used for my RealTest thanks to the @ContextConfiguration Annotation

```
<bean id="Service" class="...ServiceImpl" >
 <property name="session">
  getSession()?? // What's the syntax or how to do this?
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read about [bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes). It doesn't really make sence the kind of injection You're trying to do. You should not inject the session itself to the business service classes. You should use the `session` scoped beans instead.
2. The test class itself **is not** a part of the test ApplicationContext, so You **cannot** autowire the values created in the test class to the test class. Anyway, why would You do that? You already have it **in** the test class, so why not just use simple setter in `@Before public void setUp() {}` method? Or see the next point.
3. If You have classes that have dependecies created inside the test class, than the `@ContextConfiguration` will be of no help here. You can use [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) by creating inside the test class an inner `@Configuration` class and configure the service class using `Spring Java Config`.

i.e.:

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class RealTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appCtx;

    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext testCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        testCtx.setParent(this.appCtx);
        testCtx.register(RealTestCfg.class);
        testCtx.refresh();

        this.service = BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType(testCtx, Service.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class RealTestCfg {

        @Bean
        public Session session() {
            return AbstractTest.session;
        }

        @Bean
        public Service service() {
            return new Service();
        }
    }
}
```

The `@ContextConfiguration` and parent `ApplicationContext` is optional, if You don't have any other dependencies. And `AbstractTest.session` needs to be `protected static`, or have `protected static` accessor.

Comment: 1. It do make sense I have a session used for testing in the test framework and want to inject into my businesses services. 2. I think you have misunderstood the question I want to transfer the session not from Test->Test but from Test->Session and I can of course declare a setter in the service and call setSession() from my Test but I would like Spring to handle my dependencies after all that whats it for.

Comment: As I understand You want to transfer the `Session` from the `Test` to the `Service`, that is one of `Test` depenedencies, right?

Comment: This cannot be done using `@ContextConfiguration`. Period. Becuse the test class is not a part of the `ApplicationContext` created this way. I'll extend my answer to clarify that, and an alternative solutiona I gave in 3.

Comment: I extended the answer. Do You see what I mean now?

Comment: I have given it a quick look although it might be correct I'm searching for a nicer way. I don't want to fiddle with context programmaticly from my test classes and I certainly would not want to create a new class RealTestCfg. All this makes my code much worse than the simple setter i wanted to avoid. Either I find a nice annotation, XML snippet or something which don't have much boiler code otherwise I will settle with a setter.

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer, I still look for an easier way. Now when I have looked at it some more there is some good points and I have changed my down vote to an up vote and accepted your answer. Thanks very much for your answer and time :) /Farmor